# Zebra ZT230-300dpi printer sgd command setvar

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, epl

I'm trying to change the `"device.languages"` attribute on a zebra ZT230 **label printer** with firmware: V72.19.6Z using the Zebra Setup Utilities Direct communication function.

The command the i send to the printer is the following:

```
! U1 setvar "device.languages" "epl_zpl"
```

followed by a newline character

but when I send the command: `! U1 getvar "device.languages"` the value has not been changed.

I'm connecting to the printer through LAN on port 9100 and the attribute `"device.command_override.list"` on the printer is not set.

I'm launching the command in the wrong manner or there is some protection mechanism that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
! UTILITIES
! U1 setvar "device.languages" "epl_zpl"
PRINT
```

or

```
! U1 setvar "device.languages" "epl_zpl"
PRINT
```

Answer (score 0):

We contacted Zebra Support and they stated that the model ZT230 with the 300 DPI head didn't support the *epl_zpl* language.

the last model of the series with the support of the *epl_zpl* language is the one with the 203 DPI head.

with the printer **ZT230 203DPI** the command:

`! U1 setvar "device.languages" "epl_zpl"`

worked fine.